# mscorlib.dll is an invalid CIL image

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded the new beta version of Unity (5.5.0b2) and when I open any project I always get an exception in the console that says:

> The file C:\Program Files\Unity 5.5.0b2\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib/mscorlib.dll is an invalid CIL image

I really don't have any clue to what this means and what to do about it, I can't even enter play mode, any advice on how to solve this?

I'm currently on Windows 7 64 bit, the Unity version installed is 64 bit, too, I tried installing it on the main hard drive and the secondary but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed version 5.4.0f3 and replaced the folder *MonoBleedingEdge* of the version 5.5.0b2 with the one found in the previous version.

The folder is located at *Unity 5.5.0b2\Editor\Data*.

Comment: **Unity 5.5 beta** has been upgraded to `Mono 4.4` but that is disabled by default. It is disabled because Unity is not yet done with the run-time library which is not included in the current version. This is very likely the reason why you are seeing that message about mscorlib. 

Since this is a beta version, you should file for a bug report with that project and the error message will likely be removed in the next version.